# Internet Explorer Cross Domain Iframe Login

Tags: security, internet-explorer, iframe, authentication

I have a Java web application in domain A (that we control). This application displays another website located in domain B (which we do not control) in an `iframe`. This external website was recently updated to require users to log on before they can see content. They provided us with a URL that will automatically log our users into their site. This URL works when we navigate directly to it in Internet Explorer (we get automatically logged in etc).

However, apparently there was an [update to Internet Explorer](http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000472.html#.UjIWQqOwa3k)  so that cross domain communication is not allowed. So now when the login URL is displayed in the `iframe`, it does not successfully log on (I am guessing its being blocked from creating security cookies).

Also, if we browse to the URL directly and get the security in place, then any `iframe` elements of the site will not work (I am guessing it is being blocked from accessing security cookies).

Does anyone know of a work around for this? Changing the security level on Internet Explorer is not an option (it is controlled by our company's system administrator). Internet Explorer is also our company standard, so we cannot change that (even though it works fine in Firefox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this was causes by the login site not being on the trusted sites list. Having security add it as a trusted site and pushing that to all company computers solved the issue.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering why the Zone might matter, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/internet-explorer-beware-cookie-sharing-in-cross-zone-scenarios.aspx

Comment: @EricLaw So what was argued in your answer... was the answer all along?

Comment: @MaximeRouiller Without further info from the OP, I can't say, but blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/internet-explorer-beware-cookie-sharing-in-cross-zone-scenarios.aspx is another explanation that may be relevant if P3P wasn't the answer.

Answer (score 10):

When you say "elements of the site will not work" what precisely does that mean?

"Cross-domain" interactions have *always* been restricted in **all** browsers. This is called "[same-origin-policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx)" and it's the foundation of web security. The "update" to Internet Explorer you're referring to restricts IE such that a webpage on Domain A can no longer navigate a subframe that is *inside* a page from Domain B. That restriction has been present in IE for 7+ years and is in all browsers. **This restriction is not causing your problem.**

This most likely problem here is that the subframe [fails to set a P3P header](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/17/simple-introduction-to-p3p-cookie-blocking-frame.aspx) that would permit its cookies to be stored. There are perhaps 30 duplicates on that issue on StackOverflow.

To determine if this is what you're encountering, try this:

1. In IE, click **Tools** > **Internet Options** > **Privacy tab**.
2. Set the slider to **Accept all**
3. Clear your cookies
4. Restart the browser and retry the scenario.

If this change solves the problem, then the fix is easy: configure the page which is being framed to specify its cookie policy using a `P3P` response header.

If this doesn't solve the problem, please update the question with more information that would allow others to reproduce it (e.g. traffic logs, live site URL, etc).

Comment: Downvoting useful answers when you've failed to ask a clear question is not a wise choice.

Comment: I generally do it for a couple of reasons. (1) the solution doesn't work and I want to indicate that to people that may find this in the future and (2) the posting of an answer that doesn't work can essentially kill the ticket. People may see it and think that I am just too lazy to mark it as correct. So now the visibility is reduced and I am less likely to get help. If you want me to remove the vote and then have you delete your answer, I am willing to do that.

Comment: Rachel-- Whoa, you've got a really odd understanding of how StackOverflow works. The guy who spent 8 years as the Security and Networking manager for the IE engineering team answers your question with a plausible explanation of the source of your problem, and asks for additional information which was lacking in your question. You provide that information (indicating that the *by far* most common explanation doesn't seem to apply in your case) but nevertheless downvote the answer because I didn't somehow magically guess the right answer in spite of the lack of information? Good luck with that.

Comment: Since it hurts you so much I'll remove the down vote. It says its locked unless you edit your answer, so do that and I'll up vote it. I also didn't see anywhere you asked for more information about my problem. You just said "You're wrong, it's probably this".

Comment: No, I said "The article you cited isn't the problem. The problem is almost always *this*, try it and let me know." And you tried it, and didn't let me help you debug further before downvoting.

Comment: So, let's try going down a more productive path: Is there a public URL for this server? If not, can you share a Fiddler capture of the traffic? I'm particularly interested in the HTTP headers on the request and responses.

Comment: Sadly my company restricts us from providing any information on public forums like this. The login link simple calls a ASPX path with the username and password in the parameters.

Comment: If you'd like to work with me in private (I'm an IE MVP) feel free to contact me by email. In particular, I think it would be useful for you to look at the `Cookie` request header in the failing scenario to confirm your theory that a cookie is going missing.

Comment: @EricLaw - thanks for the info. This solved my issue. For anyone else having the same issue, I added the following to my **Page_Load** - `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader ("p3p","CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");`.