# Navigation issues inside Iframe when opened in IE

Tags: javascript, html, security, internet-explorer, iframe

In IE I am facing an issue in iframe where I am not able to navigate using the links present in the web page that is opened in the iframe.

Following are more details -

My local url is : localhost:9001/ or MY_IP_ADDRESS:9001/

I am having a web page that has a Iframe inside it. I am running this web page inside my local tomcat server. The url that is used to open the web page inside the Iframe is -

**https://www.apps.website1.com/doAddEmp**

When above url is opened then it takes me to a page where i can do Add operation for an Employee if i have already logged in to website1.com else it takes me to the login page(**https://www.website1.com/doLogin**).

Now everything is fine if I am already logged in to the website1 in the browser. But if I am not logged in then it navigates me to the login page of website1,
and when I enter the credentials then it doesn't take me to the next page(**https://www.apps.website1.com/doAddEmp**) instead it reloads and brings me back to the login page.

**This works completely fine in chrome and in firefox but in IE it is giving me this issue. I have tried this in IE9 & IE10.**

I am not able to figure out what is happening over. Need a help in understanding this issue and resolving it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue was coming in IE because IE doesn't allow the third party cookies. So the site that i had opened in iframe was trying to set the cookie which is a third party cookie as that is opened in an iframe. Hence i was facing this issue -

I came to know about the issue that i was facing from the following link -

[Internet Explorer Cross Domain Iframe Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773093/internet-explorer-cross-domain-iframe-login)